# Get how many times each player get max score based on date

Tags: group-by, max

I want to find how many times each player has max score based on created_at.
In below table.

player_id 1 has two times max score on date 12 and 13. 
player_id 2 has one time max score on date 14.

So i want to check it for player_id = 1. how many time this player get max score.

```
+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+
| player_id | score |   sector    | created_at |
+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+
|         1 |    25 | Midfielder  | 2017-12-12 |
|         2 |    23 | Defender    | 2017-12-12 |
|         3 |    24 | Goalkeeper  | 2017-12-12 |
|         4 |    20 | Midfielder  | 2017-12-12 |
|         1 |    26 | Midfielder  | 2017-12-13 |
|         2 |    20 | Defender    | 2017-12-13 |
|         3 |    19 | Goalkeeper  | 2017-12-13 |
|         4 |    16 | Midfielder  | 2017-12-13 |
|         1 |    18 | Midfielder  | 2017-12-14 |
|         2 |    20 | Defender    | 2017-12-14 |
|         3 |    12 | Goalkeeper  | 2017-12-14 |
+-----------+-------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code,

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID, COUNT(*) MAX_SCORE_COUNT
FROM
(
  SELECT player_id PLAYER_ID FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME a
  WHERE a.score = ( SELECT MAX(b.score) FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME b WHERE b.created_at = a.created_at)
) s
GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
```

This query return number of times each player got max score based on `created_at`.

If you want to check it for `player_id = 1` then you can use,

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID, COUNT(*) MAX_SCORE_COUNT
FROM
(
  SELECT player_id PLAYER_ID FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME a
  WHERE a.score = ( SELECT MAX(b.score) FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME b WHERE b.created_at = a.created_at)
) s
WHERE PLAYER_ID = 1
GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
```